# Group and ungroup rows preserving all columns dynamically

Tags: powerquery

In Power Query, I want to group my table by certain columns, add a new column based on the groups, then ungroup my table again. I can do this using the GUI. But the GUI hard-codes my column names and types. If I later want to change a column name or type, it takes a long time to update.

Can I make Power Query group and ungroup all the columns, without hard-coding the column names?
I can use `Table.Schema` to access the column names and the names of the types, but it's a pain to get the types themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a group you can simply remove the code between the **[** **]**  within the group step code, and then it will operate on any columns

so that the autogenerated code

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"a"}, {{"data", each _, type table [a=nullable number, b=nullable number, c=nullable number]}})
```

becomes

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"a"}, {{"data", each _, type table }})
```

Comment: Brilliant - so much less work! Thanks. I ended up removing the columns while I was grouping the table, i.e. `#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"a"}, {{"data", each Table.RemoveColumns(_, {"a"}), type table }})`, to make it slightly more convenient, but yours is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you know in advance what column types are possible. You can use `if [Kind]="text then type text else ... else type any` to turn the type names into types. Then you have to build a record type, which uses the inconveniently-designed `Type.ForRecord` function.

If the previous step is called `Did Previous Step`, you can use the following code to group by columns `"Column A"` and `"Column B"`.

```
=Table.Group(#"Did Previous Step", {"Column A", "Column B"}, {{"AllRows", each _,
  type table Type.ForRecord(Record.FromList(
    Table.TransformRows(
      Table.Schema(#"Did Previous Step"), 
      each [Type=if [Kind]="text" then type nullable text 
            else if [Kind]="number" then type nullable number 
            else type any, Optional=false]
    ), Table.Schema(#"Inserted Merged Column")[Name]),false)}})
```

Going the other way works similarly, though you should use `List.Difference()` twice to avoid duplicating the columns that you grouped by.